# Bootstrap Columns Not Working When Resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem where if I resize the browser to small size, the columns don't work and instead each image is shown in different rows. It's shown here:

[image]

It does work correctly in bigger size which displays four images in a row. Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the way it works when you use `col-sm-3`, try `col-xs-3`.

Comment: That made the pictures stay in the same row but now the images are overlapping each other.

Comment: You're using set dimensions, use `img-responsive` class and remove the `height` and `width` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you shouldn't be using two containers. Secondly:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/sanfran.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/sanfran.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/sanfran.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/sanfran.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works as expected because `col-sm-*` are applied only above `767px`. You should use `col-xs-*` for smaller screens.

Comment: @hungerstar Thats a good advice. Consider a situation where there is deep nesting of `.row` and `.col` and another `.container` being used deep inside nesting of rows and cols. Let me find a reference of bootstrap doc suggesting the same.

Comment: @hungerstar here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-type-links in the _Containers_ section, second line: _"Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable."_.

Answer (score 0):

`col-sm-`  for tablet view. `col-xs-` for mobile view.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="  col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="  col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="267" width="187"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Two containers should not be used in bootstrap

Comment: @user31782 what if I want background which goes full screen, but contents to be in the middle?

Comment: @hungerstar I am talking about `.container` and `.container-fluid`.

Comment: @Morpheus Then you should `section` tag or `div` tag as parent of `.container` and apply background to that parent element.

Answer (score 0):

please remove width="187" and height="267" from img tag. Instead of this you can add style="max-width: 187 px; width: 100%;" with the img tag. I think it will work. Please try.
In mobile device , if you want to see 4 images in one row, you should add the class "col-xs-3" with "col-sm3".

Comment: You added fixed width for images. The reason of your problem is that there is no space for containing 4 images. Please think one image has 187px width. So 4 images need 748px. There is no space in the case of devices having width below 748px. So you need to resize the image in small devices

Comment: So just try with my answer